# C++ proper boolean and double input

Tags: c++, boolean, double

//EX.

```
bool ex;
cin >> ex;
try {
  if (ex != 0 && ex != 1)
  {
    cin.clear();
    throw ex;
  }
}
catch (bool ex)
{
//redo process
}
```

How do you check if a boolean and a double input is proper?

Comment: How are you defining "proper" input? How does your code relate to doubles? I'm not understanding how doubles relate here.

Comment: By proper I mean if the variable is a bool the user inputs a bool rather than a word. And the example doesn't have a double in it, but the question is applied to it.

Comment: You write very confusingly.

Comment: How to check if the input of the user is proper to the variable type. So that the user doesn't mess up the program by accident.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you following :

```
bool ex;
while (1) {
  if (cin >> ex) {
     if(ex ==1 || ex== 0)
      break;
  } else {
      cout<<"Error !"<<endl;
      cin.clear();
      while (cin.get() != '\n') ; 
  /* Edit: Use cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n'); 
   as suggested by Ben Voigt
   header file  - limits
  */
  }
```

Comment: There's a builtin function to do `while (cin.get() != '\n') ;`.  It is named `cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n')`.   Hmm, I guess that it isn't as pretty looking, but it won't cause an infinite loop if there's an I/O error such as end-of-file.

Answer (score 0):

How do you suppose to input a boolean value? "Yes", "1", "One", "ja", "Ja", "sí", "true", "OK", "y", ... ?

Well, what you require is a parser which parses the input and decides whether the given input string is a boolean value.

Comment: Of course, if you have a specific language in mind, you can turn on `std::ios_base::boolalpha` and `imbue()` a suitable `std::locale`. By default, `true` and `false` will be used. If you want to support just one language, you can set the strings in `std::numpunct<char>`. If you want to support multiple languages, you'll need to provide the parsing in `std::num_get<char>`.

Comment: It's always surprising how powerful the hidden gems of std streams are - assuming the locale feature is implemented correctly. ;) In the given case however, we have a user who is requested to give an input on the console, either a boolean value ("Yes" or "No" maybe?) or a number. The given problem is also a UI design problem. How would you (as the programmer) make it clear what you expect from the user and how would you implement it?  :-)

Comment: In a UI I would probably have a checkbox and get over it. If you have a text interface, you could reasonably print `question (yes/no):`. As I said, you can make the code accept multiple values but you'd need to provide a suitable `std::num_get<char>` facet which overrides the appropriate `do_get()` function. Also, I'm not aware of any standard library which gets the `std::locale` stuff wrong! It is implemented everywhere as far as I know of. The need to do something like the locales falls out of having to support multiple character types anyway.